# HTML tags are treated as strings for XSS

Tags: javascript, html, security, xss

This is an XSS-related question:

I tried entering `\'';!--"<XSS>=&{()})` in a search box, and all the characters are being displayed on the page, ie, none are filtered out.

When I click "Inspect Element", I see that this text is being displayed within 2 `<strong>` tags, which are inside `<h2>` tags, which are inside a `<div>`. I tried inserting `<div onmouseover="alert(1)">hi</div>` but it is just getting displayed as is, and when I inspect the text, I see that it is not being registered as HTML, it is just treated as a string.

Also, if I try breaking the `<strong>` tags with `</strong> <div onmouseover="alert(1)"> hi </div> <strong>`, the tag is not being broken, and it is just being displayed directly.

Why are these HTML tags treated as strings, and not as actual tags?

Comment: What do you see if you use "View Source" rather than "Inspect Element"? You should see that characters like `<` are encoded as html entities.

Comment: So they properly escaped the html to the html entities.

Comment: I don't understand how stopping a XSS is a problem...

Comment: In the page source, I see `&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;strong&gt;`

Is there no way to bypass these HTML entities?

BubbleHacker: I'm trying to learn XSS, not stop it :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not misunderstanding the question, you are trying to learn hacking. And I guess you are trying to hack a professional website. If so, then they have already thought of that threat and probably made a PHP function against it.

So, you would be lucky to find a website with that vulnerability. Your only option to learn it is to set up your local PHP server(xampp, wamp...), download a non-secure page try it there.

But this isn't the site to ask this question because this is for programming questions. You can go to http://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: You are correct (I am trying to learn ethical hacking), except I'm not trying it on a professional website (by which I assume you mean Google, Microsoft, etc). Thanks for the tip!